# Month and year by Average using excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have data as given in the picture the data starts from Nov-2015 to March-2020 so want the average for each month year wise as shown in the output.

Please note that there are lots of dates on which data is missing so that dates are not avilable for Ex after 13 march the next entry was on 16 March.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bracket the dates in AVERAGEIFS:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(2020,3,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(2020,4,1))
```

Comment: How to get values for other months

Comment: Change the dates.

Comment: Isn't that time consuming I have lots of months so need to change dates for each month

Comment: Look into pivot tables, that will do it quicker.